# Take MySQL backup for last 10 days by using bash script

Tags: bash

Following is the script is scheduled on MYSql DataBase which is on linux server.
Following is code using bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# MySQL backup script
# Last update: 20090504
#

MHOST=localhost
MUSER=backup
MPASS=OwBPimRc
BACKUPDIR="/mnt/backup"

########################################################################

MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

DBPREFIX="$(hostname -s).mysqldb"

echo "Run MySQL backup"
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
  FILE=${BACKUPDIR}/${DBPREFIX}.${db}.gz
  $MYSQLDUMP --no-tablespaces --skip-lock-tables -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
done
```

But I want to customise this process like
1. with the help of above bash script, i want to store laste 10 database back up
please suggest bash scripts commands to do the same..

Best Regards
Arvind

Comment: This is a pure Bash shell script; not Perl.

Comment: sorry for confusion..yes this is shell scripting. The perl script is scheduled which check the database back up was done properly or not. can you please move this post under respective group

Comment: Have a look at http://gehrcke.de/2010/11/mysql-backup-script-with-email-support-and-lzma-compression-for-cron/.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
MHOST=localhost
MUSER=backup
MPASS=OwBPimRc
BACKUPDIR="/mnt/backup"

MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

DBPREFIX="$(hostname -s).mysqldb"

echo "Run MySQL backup"
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
    FILE=${BACKUPDIR}/${DBPREFIX}.${db}.`date +%Y%m%d`.gz
    $MYSQLDUMP --no-tablespaces --skip-lock-tables -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
done 

find  -name "${BACKUPDIR}/${DBPREFIX}*" -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm -f '{}' ';'
```

The basic idea is to use the date in the filename to get distinct database backups for each day. In the last line you can delete all files that are older than 10 days, leaving only the 10 most recent backups intact.

Comment: Be careful with putting your password in the command like this. Other users on the machine will be able to read it in the process list. Use something like `$(cat passwordfile)` as described here: http://gehrcke.de/2010/11/mysql-backup-script-with-email-support-and-lzma-compression-for-cron/

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply. But here i can see that the back up is created with respective of date, can i create new folder and in that folder want to store last 10 back up? how i can do that. I mean in the folder /mnt/backup we have 10 folders which will store last 10 datebase files? for that how can i modify above code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution from jOnes is reasonable. Here's another alternative: Leave the script alone, and use "[logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)" to handle the pruning. In your `/etc/logrotate.conf`,  you would put something like this:

```
   /mnt/backup/*.mysqldb {
       daily
       rotate 10
       missingok
       nocompress
   }
```

See `man logrotate` to confirm which options would work best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late since the question is 3 years old, but I thought I could add a little more functionality to jOnes script.
I needed a similar script, but since it could be run multiple times a day, the "rotate" part didn't work well for me.

Moreover, I think the OP needed a way to keep only the last "n" backups of each database, while jOnes version keeps the last "n" backup files  (so if you have 11 databases in your server, only the first 10 will be kept).

Here's my version:

```
MHOST=localhost
MUSER=backup
MPASS=OwBPimRc
BACKUPDIR="/mnt/backup"
MAXBACKUPS=10

MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

DBPREFIX="$(hostname -s).mysqldb"

echo "Run MySQL backup"
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
    FILE=${BACKUPDIR}/${DBPREFIX}.${db}.`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.gz
    $MYSQLDUMP --no-tablespaces --skip-lock-tables -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE

    TOTBACKUPS=$[`ls -l ${BACKUPDIR}/${DBPREFIX}.${db}* | wc -l` - 1]
    if [ $TOTBACKUPS > $MAXBACKUPS ]
    then
        TBREMOVED=$[TOTBACKUPS - MAXBACKUPS + 1]
        REMLIST=`ls -ctr ${BACKUPDIR}/${DBPREFIX}.${db}*  | head -n ${TBREMOVED}`
        for i in $REMLIST
        do
            rm -rf $i
        done
    fi    

done
```